# Iscroll - Infinite - with random cell sizes

Tags: web-applications, infinite-scroll, iscroll

Hi there I know that's not neccessarily the functionality of the Iscroll-Infinite as it seem to be only scrolling the cells of equal sizes. Maybe any of you already resolved the issue I am having - basically I need it to work with different cell sizes not just set size. Whilst the library works perfect with set size cell the random sizing proves difficult to implement.

I'm not too hooked on the iscroll anyway - if anyone of you know of a good Angular extension that works the same or point me in the right direction on how to achieve it with something else. then I'd very much appreciate the help.

Comment: Forgot to add I require pixel perfect scroll event (firing when inertia kicks in) so native mobile scrolling is not really an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the answer to the above is - its absolutely possible but not using iscroll-infinite (at least at the moment) but your own solution with iscroll. On scroll event there are two properties available to you that you can actively change whilst scrolling and achieve never-ending scroll effect (IScroll.scrollerHeight and IScroll.maxScrollY) keep the initial scrollerHeight and keep updating maxScrollY with each cell you reappend at the end of the feed. This also will require some caching/server communication to achieve the full "infinite scroll" functionality.

I can confirm that this absolutely works brilliantly.